# Referrer website not being rewritten by webserver

Tags: php, ssl, google-analytics, header

I have a situation like the following:

- **Source traffic:** a network of different HTTP, non-SSL protected websites where visitors come from and go to Middle page.
- **Middle page:** a page on a (Let's Encrypt) SSL-protected domain with `header("Referrer-Policy: no-referrer");` that redirects to the Second Middle Page.
- **Second middle page:** another page, on the same (Let's Encrypt) SSL-protected domain, with `header("Referrer-Policy: no-referrer");` that redirects to the Destination Website.
- **Destination website:** a simple HTTP website, with no SSL, with Google Analytics.

Could there be any case in which Google Analytics or any other visitor tracking services shows up the Source Traffic as referrer, even a most remote one?

As far as it might seem ridicolous, this is simply what is happening to me. I was sure that, even if a referrer should ever show up, it should be at least rewritten by the Middle pages. Am I wrong?

Comment: Casuistry - _"a resolving of specific cases of conscience, duty, or conduct through interpretation of ethical principles or religious doctrine"_. Are your sure you used that correctly ?

Comment: I wanted to write "case" actually. Pardon.

Answer (score 0):

> A user agent MUST NOT send a Referer header field in an unsecured HTTP
> request if the referring page was received with a secure protocol.

[From here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2). I'd say your referrer information is lost as you switch between secure and insecure sites. Since the point of secure protocols is to prevent data from leaking out to not secured sites this makes sense, too.

Comment: What it seems to happen is this: visitor coming from http source goes to https page, then gets redirected to a final website via http. If I check the final website stats, I see the first http source as a referral. Is this actually possible?